# Unity - Argument Exception

Tags: c#, unity3d

Появилась непонятная ошибочка в MonoDevelop.

> Error Error: System.ArgumentException: ќ«Ґ¬Ґ­в б вҐ¬ ¦Ґ Є«оз®¬ г¦Ґ Ўл«                  ¤®Ў ў«Ґ­. (Error: System.ArgumentException) (Assembly-UnityScript)'

Не указывает ни на какую строку, хотя по смыслу понятно что что-то не то с аргументами в функциях, и оно должно было указать на проблемную строку. Я проверил вызовы функций, везде все в порядке..
UPD: Не заметил на что оно влияет, приложение запускается без траблов..
Но очень интересно что-же за ошибочка..

Comment: Дешифратор выдал "Элемент с тем же ключом уже был добавлен". Где-то в базу данных добавляешь запись с совпадающим primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверь **DEBUG** и **TRACE**. раздел **DefineConstants** файлов проекта Unity `.csproj` и `.unityproj` файлы

или попробуй сделать так: Нажми правой кнопкой на **Assembly-UnityScript** (в левом дереве) -> параметры -> компилятор 
и удали первый  **DEBUG** и **TRACE**